# I am trying to use jekyll, and it does not generate the whole directory structure; what's wrong?

Tags: web, jekyll, jekyll-bootstrap

This is what I have done:

```
gem install jekyll bundler
jekyll new staticwebsite
cd staticwebsite
jekyll build
```

What I get is this:

[image: enter image description]

It is not clear to me what is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Since Jekyll 3.2.0  **gem based themes** are the default, this is why you are not seeing all the typical structure that used to be before them:

> Our flagship feature for this release has been themes. Themes?!, you
>   say? Yes, proper, versionable, releasable, first-class themes. We’re
>   pretty stoked about it and we hope you like building and using them.
>   For now, it only supports layouts, includes, and sass, but we have
>   plans to include static assets like images and CSS/JS in a future
>   release.

That basically means that by default you won't have these typical directories:

```
/assets
/_layouts
/_includes
/_sass
```

But Jekyll will use the ones in each theme, unless you overwrite them or copy to your jekyll instance to [modify them](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/themes/).

Answer (score 0):

When you check your _config file you will see that

> theme: minima

and that mean your jekyll use `minima` gem  and to locate the file of minima theme use the command `bundle show minima`

[image]

to get the path of minima and open the file location to see the files that will use in your jekyll site 
[image]

For more information check [Jekyll Themes](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/themes/)